# adding JSON data to google pie chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to add Json data to my pie chart but can't find a way to do it

This is a controller which fetches the JSon data,I want to add it to the piechart

```
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);


   app.controller("piecontroller", function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.msg = "hi";

        $http.get("http://10.155.4.219:8080/gst/rest/test/approved") .then(function(response) {
        $scope.mydata = response.data;


    });
});
```

Following code is the js file for the piechart I have added a few hardcoded values but I need to dynamically add JSON data'

```
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([


          ['status', 'count'],
  ['Deemed approved', 185],
  ['approved', 628],

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'New Resgisteration'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
           }
```

JSON DATA

```
{
    "Details": [{
        "count": "185",
        "type": "Deemed approved ",
        "desc": "New registration"
    }, {
        "count": "628",
        "type": "Approved ",
        "desc": "New registration"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);


   app.controller("piecontroller", function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.msg = "hi";

        $http.get("http://10.155.4.219:8080/gst/rest/test/approved") .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.mydata = response.data;
        drawChart(response.data); // or pass response.data;
    });
});

 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart(data) {
        var chartArray = data.Details.map(item =>[item.type, item.count]);
        chartArray.push(['Task', 'Hours per Day'])
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartArray);

        var options = {
          title: 'New Resgisteration'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
           }
```

Comment: pie.js:31 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Details' of undefined
    at drawChart (pie.js:31)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: console the response pass the json to drawChart{Details:...}?

Comment: ?? did not get you

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet can you show me what is response.data? you have to pass data to drawChart like this{Details:[{..}]}

Comment: console.log(response.data); is not displayed because of the error

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet put console.log() before calling drawChart. i will modify the answer.check it.

Comment: same error tried it 
doesnt show If you want I can show it to you it used to display without your code

Comment: here it is {Details: Array(2)}
Details
:
Array(2)
0
:
$$hashKey
:
"004"
count
:
"185"
desc
:
"New registration"
type
:
"Deemed approved "
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
$$hashKey
:
"005"
count
:
"628"
desc
:
"New registration"
type
:
"Approved "
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet did you get the response.data?

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet then pass that data to drawCharts.why you cant read the data.Details?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Details' of undefined
    at drawChart (pie.js:31)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: line no 31  var chartArray = data.Details.map(item =>[item.type, item.count]);

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet console.log(data.Details) in drawChart before line no 31.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Details' of undefined
    at drawChart 
    at <anonymous>
console.log(data.Details) gives error

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet data is undefined.thats why you are not passing the data to drawChart function.or data is not getting ..pass after the promise is resolved. ithink you are calling drawChart before the promise is resolved.

Comment: this is what i get for console.log()
(2) [{…}, {…}]

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{count: "185", type: "Deemed approved ", desc: "New registration"}
1
:
{count: "628", type: "Approved ", desc: "New registration"}
length
:
2

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet if you are getting data.Details as this then how did you got undefined?then data.Details.map should work.it will not cause any error